# How can i use "loop for" in this situation?

Tags: lisp, clisp

The following code will raise: SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: (SETQ NUM (SUBSTRING LINE 6)) should be a lambda expression.

```
(defun good-red ()
  (let ((tab (make-hash-table)))
    (dotimes (i 50) (setf (gethash (+ i 1) tab) 0))
    (with-open-file (stream "ssqHitNum.txt")
        (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
             until (null line)
             do (
                (setq num (substring line 6))
                (print line)
                )))))
```

If i change the "do" as below, it works. However, i need to do many things here.

```
 ...
 do (print line)
 ...
```

Sincerely!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the outermost set of parens like this.

```
(loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
         until (null line)
         do 
            (setq num (substring line 6))
            (print line))
```

The loop body has an implicit `progn` around it, when you add the extra parens the reader will expect the first thing in the list (in this case `(setq num (substring line 6))` to be a symbol with a function.  Obviously the `setq` form does not meet that criteria and so it will fail, though I'm not sure why it tells you it should be a lambda expression.

A style note:

Do not use parens as you would curly braces in Java or C++!

```
do (
     &body
   )
```

is bad Lisp style, close all parens on the last line as I have in my answer and open parens on the same line as the form the left paren begins.

Answer (score 3):

You need the [PROGN special form](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_progn.htm) to evaluate all of those expressions in order.

```
...
do (progn
     (setq num (substring line 6))
     (print line))
...
```

Comment: You don't actually need a `progn` here, you just need to remove the outermost set of parens.  `(loop ... do ...)` has an implicit progn after do.